# WordPress 404 page by wrong url

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

For now only if im entering page id which doesnt exist I get the 404 page.
http://EXAMPLE.COM/?page_id=51573

But its not redirecting to 404 page if im going to http://EXAMPLE.COM/blablabla

is that possible to redirect those kind of addresses to 404 page in wordpress?

Comment: Yes, add a .htaccess file specific to wordpress and enable permalinks.

Comment: what should I write in the HTACCESS file?

Comment: just go to wp admin panel, enable permalinks from settings and after enabling, you will get the htaccess code that you will have to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a `.htaccess` file and upload it to your WordPress root directory. In your `.htaccess` write the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In your WordPress dashboard go to `Settings > Permalinks` there you choose the structure you'd like. In your case this would be postname.

Answer (score 1):

1- Create a 404.php page into your theme directory

2- Be sure your server allows the wordpress to manage the permalinks.

3- then every page will be redirect to your customized 404.php page

More info about creating 404 error page here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Comment: His theme already has a 404 page, since it's being displayed when entering a bad page ID.

Comment: were did you saw that? Normally a payed wordpress theme and maybe those free ones already have a 404 page. You «just need to allow into your server the wordpress to manage the permalinks.

Comment: He said a page with an invalid post ID gives him the 404 error page, meaning it already exists.